# Unity 2D Collider not centered in Transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[the duder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZkf5.png)

My character in a school group project somehow ended up offcenter of the transform, which I believe is messing with a few issues when instantiating weapons and projectiles.

How do I fix this?

[collider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd1W7.png)
[transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlYiq.png)

Edited the box collider offsets but to no avail. Not sure what else to do, messing with the transform (predictably) messes with the collider in ways I don't want.

Comment: If you have child objects in your character object which are not in the center it will change the center of the transform of your parent object.

Comment: there are no child objects in my character

Comment: Can you edit your post and add a screenshot of your scene hierarchy and make visible all objects?